# Why I get "No Vala Compiler Found" while compiling?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, compiling, unity-greeter

I tried to install Unity Greeter (`unity-greeter_0.2.8.orig.tar.gz`) to my Ubuntu 12.04 system from source. But after enter `./configure` in terminal, following error appeared:

[image: This is snapshot for above error]

Comment: You should copy and paste the information as pure text into your Question instead as a picture. It will load quickly and is more useful.

Comment: Why are you building from source? And if so, any reason not use the source package and use `debuild`?

Answer (score 3):

Building the original package is like this:

1. Get the source package

   ```
   apt-get source unity-greeter
   ```
2. Install the build dependencies (this will install the missing Vala compiler for you!):

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep unity-greeter
   ```
3. Build it

   ```
   cd unity-greeter-0.2.8
   debuild -uc -us
   ```
4. Install the package(s) built:

   ```
   cd ..
   ls -al *.deb
   sudo dpkg -i unity-greeter*.deb
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The terminal output is telling you that, when it cannot find the software `valac`. So you have to install this compiler to *compile* (if redundancy is allowed) your application and install it.

To install your missing library/compiler enter the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libvala-0.22* valac-0.22*
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to install the valac compiler

```
sudo apt-get install valac
```

full install details at

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaOnLinux